# UnityWebRequest filling up Memory when using it to load images repeatedly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, unitywebrequest

Im using UnityWebRequest to load an image.

This is the code.

```
            UnityWebRequest uwr;
            StartCoroutine(LoadImageCorroutine());
            IEnumerator LoadImageCorroutine()
            {
                using (uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(@"file:///C://UnityTests/Filerepository/Items/3faju5ozafrz.png"))
                {
                    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
                    rawImage.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);

                    //Debug.Log(i.ToString());
                }
                uwr.Dispose();
                StopCoroutine(LoadImageCorroutine());
            }
```

I ran some performance test and noted that the Memory usage where going up and up each time I called the coroutine and didnt go down afterwards.

Considering the CPU load going down with time, it seems the coroutine either properly stopping or at least going idle.

How do I get rid of whatever UnityWebRequest is loading into my Memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Myself already ran into this issue once before. You can see what happens by using the [profiler (<kbd>CTRL + 7</kbd>)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and do a [memory snapshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html)

- Click on the Memory module
- At the bottom switch from "Simple" to "Detailed"
- Click on <kbd>Take Sample</kbd>
- Checkout "Assets" → "Texture2D"

before and after running your routine.

SPOILER: You will see that after every run of your download routine there is one more texture asset in the memory which is never destroyed.

The thing is that any `Texture` downloaded via `UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture` is **not GC collected** even if it is nowhere referenced anymore! So each run of the coroutine adds one more texture instance to your memory.

---

In order to solve this once you know you actually want to destroy the texture you'll have to do so "manually":

```
IEnumerator LoadImageCorroutine()
{
    using (var uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(@"file:///C://UnityTests/Filerepository/Items/3faju5ozafrz.png"))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        // I would always check for errors first
        if(uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Could not load texture do to {uwr.responseCode} - \"{uwr.error}\"", this);
            yield break;
        }

        // Destroy the current texture instance
        if(rawImage.texture) 
        {
            Destroy(rawImage.texture);
        }
     
        rawImage.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);

        //Debug.Log(i.ToString());
    } 

    // since you are using "using" there is no need to call Dispose() manually

    // This is anyway the end of your coroutine .. you do not want to call
    // StopCoroutine(LoadImageCorroutine()) here
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem.